# backbone.model.fetch success not getting jqXHR

Tags: javascript

I am doing

```
var x = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : xyz})
x.fetch({

success : function (response){
console.log(response);
}


})
```

Not able to get jqXHR object.